# Can I do a jUnit Test in the Same Class as My Main Code?

Tags: java, junit

I am new to jUnit and I am finding testing the small project I'm working on difficult. All the examples for jUnit testing seem to involve math, and what I wrote is a simple application that takes information via Scanner and creates various objects and stores them in an ArrayList. One of my thoughts was to test if the ArrayList was empty, but I obviously cannot access it from a separate class, but the standard seems to be to separate the test from the code.  So I am not sure what to do?

Comment: Best practice is to put the tests in a separate class, so that when it's time to release your program to the world, you can release just the application classes and not the test classes.  In this case, don't think about checking whether the array list is empty - instead, think about how objects of the class might behave differently when that array list is empty.  Then write tests for the behaviour of the objects, not tests for their internal state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could provide a protected accessor for the array so that it can be used by the unit tests (which should be in the same package).

Answer (score 1):

The typical well established practices are:

- Unit test and production code goes into different files living in different projects but using the same package names.
- Unit tests should *not* rely on internal state of production code. You don't want to write a test that needs to know about a field within the class under test. Because that means that your test can break when you change the production code to solve the problem differently.

The real answer here: you should share pieces of your code with us, to receive really helpful feedback.